# How to create an instance of a class and override its function in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How would I write the following code in Kotlin?

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiever() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

}}
```

Comment: You can copy-paste this code into Android Studio and the code will automatically convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {...}
}
```